# Why sql function return null?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Get_Price_For_Circulation] (@TypeID int, @Count int, @Info xml)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    declare @Result float;

    if @TypeID = 9
    BEGIN
        if @Count = 50
            set @Result = 400;
        else if (@Count = 100)
            set @Result = 600;
        else if (@Count = 250)
            set @Result = 1000;
        else if (@Count = 500)
            set @Result = 1700;
        else if (@Count = 1000)
            set @Result = 2600;
        else if (@Count = 2000)
            set @Result = 4000;
    END
        RETURN @Result;
END
```

And I have C# code

```
cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;
cn.Open();

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[fn_Get_Price_For_Circulation]", cn);
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TypeID", SqlDbType.Int);
myCommand.Parameters["@TypeID"].Value = typeID;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Count", SqlDbType.Int);
myCommand.Parameters["@Count"].Value = pCount;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Info", SqlDbType.Xml);
myCommand.Parameters["@Info"].Value = selxml!=null? selxml.ToString():"";

return myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

When I send `@TypeID=9`, `@Count=50`, `@Info=""`, C# returns null, but when I send the same parameters from SQL Server Management Studio, the function returns 400. Why?

**Update**: I found solution

```
 myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Float);
 myCommand.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

 return myCommand.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value;
```

Comment: I am not aware that you can execute a function as a stored procedure.  Try using `select dbo.fn_Get_PriceFor_Circulation(. . . `.

Comment: I guess functions cannot be called directly. They have to be part of a select statement. I would change the commandType to Text and call it 'Select fn_Get_Price_For_Circulation'

Comment: Do the same way you do in MSSQL Explorer.. use `select [dbo].[fn_Get_Price_For_Circulation]..`

Comment: Even if you call this correctly it can still return NULL because your variable only gets set to a value if @ TypeID = 9 AND @ Count in (50,100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000). If the above extremely precise condition is not met your return will be NULL.

Comment: Is this only example code? As I'm wondering why you're using a sql function to do something that's easier to do in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see people have said this in comments, but I'll put it in code form.

You're attempting to call a User Defined Function as if it were a stored procedure. Unfortunately, these are very different things. What you're looking for is to call it through a `SELECT` statement:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT fn_Get_Price_For_Circulation(@TypeID, @Count, @Info)", cn))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID", typeID);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count", pCount);

    if (selxml == null)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Info", string.Empty);
    else
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Info", selxml.ToString());

    return myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

I've also taken the liberty, just for readability's sake, of changing your parameters to use `AddWithValue`.

As for why it might be returning `NULL`, that's a question of whether your function is written properly. Right now, you check to see whether result is one of many values. Are you sure you don't mean to test whether it's between them?

```
if @Count < 50
    set @Result = 400;
else if (@Count < 100)
    set @Result = 600;
else if (@Count < 250)
    set @Result = 1000;
else if (@Count < 500)
    set @Result = 1700;
else if (@Count < 1000)
    set @Result = 2600;
else if (@Count < 2000)
    set @Result = 4000;
```

Now, this is mostly just a guess. This might *not* be what you want, but, and I say this without knowledge of your application, it seems far more likely to be what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: This code only part of sql functions. Thx for help!